# NPM native builds with only Visual Studio 2013 installed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, npm

I've got a clean install of Windows with Visual Studio 2013 Pro installed, along with current versions of Python, node and npm.

I'm trying to install the `pg` npm package, but it requires a native build and is failing:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(64,5):
>   error MSB8020: The build tools for  Visual Studio 2012 (Platform
>   Toolset = 'v110') cannot be found. To build using the v110 build
>   tools, please install Visual Studio 2012 build tools.  Alternatively,
>   you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the
>   Project menu or right
>   -click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...".
>   [C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pg\build\binding.vcxproj]

I can't seem to find Build tools for Visual Studio 2012 as described, and I'd certainly prefer to not need to install VS2012 just for this one need. Is there a way to force the install and build to use the available 2013 compiler/tools, without changing the code of the package?

I couldn't find anyone describing this specific problem and a solution using my Googlefu.

Comment: You can supply other versions with --msvs_version=2012 (for example) in npm. I don't think there is an official 2013 switch/

Comment: This looks like the list of flags here? http://code.google.com/p/gyp/source/browse/trunk/pylib/gyp/MSVSVersion.py?r=1725

Comment: Even better, you can set the version globally too, e.g.
npm config set msvs_version 2012 --global

Comment: @ErikVullings - So, `npm config set msvs_version 2013 --global`? (As the question was about using VS 2013)

Answer (score 17):

I have too clean install of Windows 8.1 (64bit) Pro with Visual Studio 2013 only (no previous version of VS, although some components came with SQL Server 2014). The `npm install` command failed with similar error.

So I tried to specify VS version

```
npm install --msvs_version=2013 <package>
```

It started correctly using Platform Toolset 'v120' but the build failed with the following error (note the `V110` used in the path for targets):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools.`

I went to the path `c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\` and found there two subfolders: `V110` and `V120`.

To correct the path used for targets I had to set environment variable like this:

```
set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120
```

Then the package got installed.

For reference, the versions:
VS 2013 Premium
Python 2.7.8
`C:\Windows\system32>npm version
{ http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.29',
  v8: '3.14.5.9',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.27',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1h',
  npm: '1.4.14' }`

Comment: Thanks, those first 2 steps fixed it for me.

Comment: After a clean install of VS 2013 I have no folderes at all in MSBuild/Microsoft.Cpp!

Comment: Been trying for a day to make this work. I wish these magic environment variables were documented somehow. You are a legend!

Answer (score 10):

What helped me is to specify environment variable *GYP_MSVS_VERSION* to to use correct VS
you can set it in Control center or in console before running npm, so for 2013 it is

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013
```

and for 2015 you use

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
```

With free VS 2013 or 2015 community edition it should be the easiest way.

PS
I believe for VS 2013 Express you should use

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013e
```

where **e** tells npm to use express version

Comment: Amazing. Been chasing around this issue and never found a solution. I had VS 2015 Enterprise installed and The following command without quotes "set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015" fixed my issue!

Answer (score 3):

Updated `node-gyp` to the latest version (1.0.2) by: `npm install node-gyp -g`

Note that you also have to [update the `node-gyp` that is internally used by node](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Updating-npm's-bundled-node-gyp)

Now, `node-gyp` will support your Visual Studio 2013 - you can check in the `<npm-cache>/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/MSVSVersion.py`, in `_CreateVersion` method.

*However*, the native modules still won't build, giving an error that some include files are missing (ones from Windows SDK, like say `winsock2.h`). That is because Visual Studio 2013 is bundled with 7.1A SDK as the default. But default Toolset setting is 'v120', which expects the 8.1 SDK (which needs to be installed additionally).

To build with just the stock VS 2013, you need to change what toolset is being selected. You can do that by modifying `~/.node-gyp/common.gypi` file (idea taken from [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/112)), and changing the toolset to 'v120_xp' instead (which will use the bundled 7.1A SDK):

`{
  ...
  'target_defaults': {
     ...
     'configurations': {
        ...
        'Release': {
          'conditions': [
            ['target_arch=="x64"', {
              'msvs_configuration_platform': 'x64',
              'msbuild_toolset': 'v120_xp'            <--- THIS LINE!
            }],
        }
     }
  }
}`

Voila - now the native npm modules will compile with the stock Visual Studio 2013 install!

Answer (score 3):

```
npm config set msvs_version 2013 --global
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar errors with VS2015 but setting the msvs param:

`npm install --msvs_version=2015`

was not solving the problem. I could see that it was looking in the wrong place for the toolset no matter what I did.

Long story short I learned that MSBuild is now packaged with Visual Studio and no longer packaged with .NET. Sure enough I had this entry in the PATH variable:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;
```

and consequently the wrong (old) version of MSBuild was being called. I removed this entry and added the following path which is relevant for VS2015:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\
```

Problem solved.