# Node packages not building on Windows 8.1 - Missing Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, node.js, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

NPM packages are not building on Windows 8.1 - failing with following error,

`error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

I have tried the following,

- Setting an evironment variable `VCTargetsPath` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\` (The error changes accordingly but there is no `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props` with the 2012 build tools).
- Installing a VisualStudio 2010 environment (uninstalled then installed in the correct order) according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16213408/199)
- Completely removed VisualStudio 2010 and tried a VisualStudio 2012 instead, which should work according to the  [`Node-gyp` wiki](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp)
- Added registry keys according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222039/199)
- Tried using the Windows 7.1 SDK command prompt according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20408394/199)
- Tried setting `VisualStudioVersion` before running npm according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736102/199)
- Tried passing `--msvs_version=2012` to npm according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16854333/199)

None of the above have worked.

I've spent ages on this already. Does anyone have a definite answer that works?

Comment: It is located in the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110 directory.  Put there by the VS2012 installer.  VCTargetsPath needs to point there.

Comment: I tried this as well, it actually requires the path without the `V11.0` on the end but it still did not work ...

Comment: Got something similar, but using VS 2013 on Windows 7. To solve it, I used the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013" to run `npm install`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it is 2.47am - figured it out.

Although the [node-gyp site seems to suggest using Visual Studio 2010 or 2012](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp), instead for Windows 8.1, install [Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832280&clcid=0x409) as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/343).

Answer (score 51):

The quick fix for me was this:

```
set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120
npm install
```

Comment: And if this folder doesn't exist on your machine install the latest VS Community IDE https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx and restart. This new folder will be set by default: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140.

Comment: In my case, had to switch V120 to V140 for this to work. Make sure to actually check where the directory path leads in explorer.

Comment: This quick fix works also to make node-openzwave-shared compile (https://github.com/OpenZWave/node-openzwave-shared)

Comment: PowerShell version: `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("VCTargetsPath", "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140", "Machine")`

Answer (score 16):

Finally Microsoft is providing [much better solution](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245) to VS.

Comment: yup, looks like that helps regardless of other VS stuff preinstalled

Comment: Direct link for Visual C++ Build Tools (the subject of the GitHub comment linked above): http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: New link to download build tools https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to update this question with the latest answer. You now do not need to install Visual Studio.

Source: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245

Instructions below in case the source goes down.

1. Install [VC++ Build Tools Technical Preview](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126) using the **Default Install** option.

   > [Windows 7 only] requires [.NET Framework 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773)
2. Install [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/), and add it to your PATH: `npm config set python python2.7`
3. Launch cmd and run:
   `npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global` (this is instead of l`npm install [package name] --msvs_version=2015l` every time.)

Comment: The VC++ Build Tools link above is broken. Better link is here: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Answer (score 5):

Setting the following fixed the problem for me

```
/property:VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120
```

As mentioned on this [forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75c3e6c2-3c24-49b8-8cd4-e0de3d8c157c/why-does-msbuild-look-for-v110-directory-for-the-microsoftcppdefaultprops-file-with-vs2013?forum=msbuild)

Comment: Where to specify `/property` ? If specified to `npm install` it is not passed to MSBuild..

Comment: You can edit `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v<Version>\msbuild.rsp` to set up global MSBuild properties.

Comment: I can't edit C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v<Version>\msbuild.rsp. I get the warning, 'Please check this file is opened in another program' But  I don't have any other program running.

Answer (score 3):

A quick note for people who installed:

1. Visual Studio 2012 (Express)
2. MSBuild 2012

with the issue of:

1. MSBuild loads Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props
2. MSBuild cannot load Microsoft.Cpp.props

The solution is here:
set parameter of MSBuild:
/property:VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110"

Comment: I have the same issue (1) but with Visual Studio 2015.
`The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found.` 

So i recon i should use `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140` (the path exists) but where to set this MSBuild parameter?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same issue as described here

[NPM native builds with only Visual Studio 2013 installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051318/npm-native-builds-with-only-visual-studio-2013-installed)

If you have a version of VS2013 installed set this environment variable before running the npm command:

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013
```

or for VS2012

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2012
```

background reading: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1151

Answer (score 1):

Just in case people encounter this issue again, the issue got resolved in my case when I did a

`npm install -g --production windows-build-tools`

[Link for reference](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/blob/master/README.md)

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658832/npm-install-error-msb3428-could-not-load-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-ex)