# Is there Oracle driver for Node.JS that does not require C++ compiler (Microsoft Visual Studio)?

Tags: node.js, oracle

I'm writing a small program on Windows platform using Node.JS which accesses Oracle database for basic insert/update operations. This program will then be deployed to a few computers with different version of Windows.

At the start I thought it would be quite straightforward by installing and using [node-oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb). However after reading the [Installation Guide](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127) and a few try, I found it's a bit clunky to install, as it requires Microsoft Windows SDK or Visual Studio which are huge, also there were lots of issues related to npm-gyp and Visual Studio (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658832/npm-install-error-msb3428-could-not-load-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-ex)), Oracle Instant Client and Visual Studio reported.

Repeating such installation process on target computers could be very time-consuming and error-prone.

Does anyone know if there is any light-weight Oracle driver for Node.JS that does not require Visual Studio? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to follow the progress on supplying prebuilt node-oracledb binaries.  A community member has made binaries available.  See https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/18#issuecomment-146434124

Comment: Thanks Chris. Just FYI I downloaded the package from github and then installed it. The installation was successful, but when I ran my test program got "The specified procedure could not be found." error. I tried DependencyWalker but it didn't tell valuable info. The OCI.DLL was found.

Comment: I re-installed the package at https://github.com/bchr02/node-oracledb after upgrading the Instant Client from 11.2 to 12.1, and it's working now! Thank you so much Chris! Unfortunately my reputation is too less to mark this answer as useful. I will do after I gain enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Installation Guide](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127), take a look at section VII. Copying Binaries Between Windows Machines.  (Towards the bottom)

If your target machines have the same versions and architecture of Node and the Oracle Instant Client installed you could go through the install once then copy the binaries between machines.

Comment: Thanks Diver. I had a look at section VII and I should be able to copy the binaries between target computers. At the moment I haven't successfully installed on one computer yet. Got "oracledb.vcproj was not found" error which was really weird.