# LINK : fatal error LNK1181:cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libeay32.lib'

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-2013, npm-install

I have windows 7 - 64 bit with Visual studio 2013 ultimate. I am running npm install command and getting below errors:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.8.3
npm info using node@v5.10.0
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 10:01:07 AM
npm http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 10:01:09 AM
npm http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ursa
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/ursa
npm info lifecycle ursa@0.9.4~preinstall: ursa@0.9.4
npm info linkStuff ursa@0.9.4
npm info lifecycle ursa@0.9.4~install: ursa@0.9.4

> ursa@0.9.4 install C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.3.1
gyp info using node@5.10.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.EXE
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2013',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sudhir_kumar05\\mockingbird\\node_modules\\ursa\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sudhir_kumar05\\.node-gyp\\5.10.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\sudhir_kumar05\\.node-gyp\\5.10.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\sudhir_kumar05\\mockingbird\\node_modules\\ursa',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\sudhir_kumar05\\mockingbird\\node_modules\\ursa\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  ursaNative.cc
..\src\ursaNative.cc(157): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(172): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(378): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(379): warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(686): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(734): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(779): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(826): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(945): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
..\src\ursaNative.cc(1003): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
  win_delay_load_hook.c
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libeay32.lib' [C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sudhir_kumar05\mockingbird\node_modules\ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v5.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm info lifecycle ursa@0.9.4~install: Failed to exec install script
npm WARN install:ursa@0.9.4 ursa@0.9.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:ursa@0.9.4 Exit status 1
npm info lifecycle mockingbird@1.0.150~preinstall: mockingbird@1.0.150
npm info linkStuff mockingbird@1.0.150
npm info lifecycle mockingbird@1.0.150~install: mockingbird@1.0.150
npm info lifecycle mockingbird@1.0.150~postinstall: mockingbird@1.0.150
npm info lifecycle mockingbird@1.0.150~prepublish: mockingbird@1.0.150
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN mongodb-core@1.2.32 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was installed.
npm info ok
```

I tried running same project in IntelliJ ultimate trial version but getting same error.

Answer (score 28):

I've had the same trouble and the answer is to read the documentation.

> OpenSSL (normal, not light) in the same bitness as your Node.js
>   installation. OpenSSL must be installed in the a specific install
>   directory (C:\OpenSSL-Win32 or C:\OpenSSL-Win64) If you get Error: The
>   specified module could not be found., copy libeay32.dll from the
>   OpenSSL bin directory to this module's bin directory, or to
>   Windows\System32.

One problem with this - you need 1.0.2 (got [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)). Version 1.1.0 has no libea32.dll.

And successively I've faced following problems installing ursa:

- node-gyp. Think it was not a real problem, but rebuilt was successful after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658832/npm-install-error-msb3428-could-not-load-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-ex)
- compiler. I had VS2010express and again error, but now when installing ursa `MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe`
  Tried out some [recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012) but only after VS2013express installation I've gor success and another error
- SSL. Use Open-SSL 64 1.0.2

Comment: The openSSL website you linked for version 1.0.2 no longer publicly lists the download for that version. The executable is still hosted, however, and I had to search through commented out HTML on that page to find the download URL. I won't list it here, since I don't know how long this will be true, but you can try it yourself if you need to.

Answer (score 7):

For Windows installing OpenSSL Version 1.1.0k, the libs were renamed from the libeay32.lib to libcrypto.dll. So the simple solution to this is to make an symbolic link using mklink in Windows. Tested on Windows 10 with Node Version 10.13.0.

Start CMD as Administrator

```
cd /d C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib
mklink libeay32.lib libcrypto.lib
```

Output should match:

```
symbolic link created for libcrypto32.lib <<===>> libcrypto.lib
```

I have done that and was building with no further issues with x509.

Source:
https://github.com/Southern/node-x509/issues/49#issuecomment-514265447

Comment: This is the best answer (either making a symbolic link, or just making a copy of the file with the other name)

Comment: This did the trick for me on Windows 10. Just make sure that, if you install OpenSSL through the installer, you choose ```C:\OpenSSL-Win64``` as your install directory and *not* the default ```"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64"```.

Answer (score 0):

Just install latest (but below 1.1) version of Windows installer for OpenSSL.
direct links across the internet get broken. This is the download page of the official website: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Answer (score 0):

yes I had a similar error but I resolved it by just changing the name of the file, but it depends on what file u are having error with, like i had a error with libeay32.lib
so i show this history of it ,its name was changed to
libeay32.lib -> libcrypto.lib ssleay32.lib -> libssl.lib
so i found the new one libssl.lib and changed it to libeay32.lib
thats it ,try !!!!!!

Comment: it works grt, had been stuck at it for hours!!