# How to solve npm install error node-gyp.js

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

When I run npm install I see following error, I am running Angular app

```
> strong-ursa@0.10.1 install C:\ANSYSDev\LicensingExternal\node_modules\strong-ursa
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\ANSYSDev\LicensingExternal\node_modules\strong-ursa>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\cygwin64\home\kjeeva\ANSYSDev\Licensing194\LicensingPortalInternal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\cygwin64\home\kjeeva\ANSYSDev\Licensing194\LicensingPortalInternal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  ursaNative.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
c:\ansysdev\licensingexternal\node_modules\strong-ursa\src\ursanative.cc(484): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'ssize_t' to 'i
nt', possible loss of data [C:\ANSYSDev\LicensingExternal\node_modules\strong-ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
c:\ansysdev\licensingexternal\node_modules\strong-ursa\src\ursanative.cc(504): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'ssize_t' to 'i
nt', possible loss of data [C:\ANSYSDev\LicensingExternal\node_modules\strong-ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libeay32.lib' [C:\ANSYSDev\LicensingExternal\node_modules\strong
-ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\cygwin64\home\kjeeva\ANSYSDev\Licensing194\LicensingPortalInternal\node\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\cygwin64\\home\\kjeeva\\ANSYSDev\\Licensing194\\LicensingPortalInternal\\node\\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\\node.exe" "C:\\cygwin64\\home\\kjeeva\\ANSYSDev\\Licensing194\\LicensingPortalInternal\\node\\node-v8.12.0-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\ANSYSDev\LicensingExternal\node_modules\strong-ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I am not sure what to do with this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINK : fatal error LNK1181:cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libeay32.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968884/link-fatal-error-lnk1181cannot-open-input-file-c-openssl-win64-lib-libeay32)

Comment: I use cygwin ssh instead of openssl