# Robotjs not working using Electron and Windows 10

Tags: javascript, electron

*I'm working on an app for Mac OSX and Windows using **Electron** and **React***. Our team of designers would like the app to have rounded borders. They want something that looks more or less like this:

[image: The design I have to implement]

**I am using the following code that works fine on Mac**

On my `main.dev.js`:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 1024,
    height: 728,
    hasShadow: false,
    frame: false, // Important!
    transparent: true // Important!
  });
```

On my `app.global.css`:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, serif;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); /* Important! */
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

On my `DisplayBar` React component:

```
class DisplayBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>);
  }
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#333333',
    borderRadius: 40, // Important!
    display: 'flex',
    height: '100%',
    border: '2px solid white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
  }
};
```

As I said it works fine on Mac however, on Windows it doesn't show anything, just a transparent screen. Do you know any solution for this problem?
[image: What my code does on windows]

PS: Greetings form Spain!

**EDIT**

I found out I have some missing dependencies problem and I have run the following command:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

I found it on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235952/5627387).

Still I get the following error on my dev tools console:

[image: Error on dev tools console]

Answer (score 0):

Iv looked over your code and everything looks fine apart from your CSS where you set the background to black (`0, 0, 0`) but you set the opacity to `0` so when you show the window it is there but the background is "invisible" because there is nothing to show.

Also I once made a window with rounded corners and ran into a problem where some corners were not rounded, I fixed this by making the window its self have a margin. This happens because when you add the border radius the border goes on the outside which in the window is out the display region so adding a margin pushes it back in.

Hope this helps you and if you run in to any problems just drop a comment.

Comment: I removed the `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);` line from the CSS and I still have the same problem. I think it has something to do with the `transparent: true` from the electron code, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try adding a width to your window, the `transparent: true` isn't a problem if you have some sort of colour/element in your window which you do

Comment: I'm just found out I have some problems with my packages. Maybe that's the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I added an edit with more info on my problem. If you know anything your help will be very much appreciated @y0hami