# Error when attempting to run Figma spellchecker extension

Tags: javascript, npm, figma-api

I have followed the instructions outlined in the readme, but I am unable to run the [spellchecker extension for Figma](https://github.com/figma/figma-api-demo/tree/master/spellchecker).

Running `npm run build` works without issue. When attempting to run `npm run spellcheck`, however, I receive the following output in console: [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjEaa.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try running

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

first and seeing if that fixes your problem?

Via: [npm install error - MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658832/npm-install-error-msb3428-could-not-load-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-ex)

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much!