# Error while installing keystonejs on windows 10

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, keystonejs

I am new to keystone Js. I am installing for first time , I could install yo and generator-keystone successfully (referred http://keystonejs.com/getting-started/) but while running the generator using yo keystone, I am getting following error.

> error: Can't find Python executable "c:\Python27\python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

why there is need of python for this nodejs framework can anyone explain? I looked for solution but at the end it says I need to install python which I can't understand.

Using 
Node 8.11.1

Npm 5.6.0

Mongo 3.6.3

Yeoman generator 2.0.1

generator keystone 0.5.1

Comment: It´s using python to organize itself and dependencies etc. on background ,because python-scripts can be the same on linux/windows/mac. So they have to maintain only one thing if they mainly use python-jobs for special support/update/.. commands. So install python, set variable and give it a try.

Comment: Yes it worked ,I can see the server running now.

Comment: But it is showing new error given below while doing "yo keystone" or installing any package using npm. Error is    : MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio
2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\keyStonePoc\node_modules\ursa\build\binding.sln]  , but I am able to run the server and see website using node keystone

Comment: @Priyanka Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235952/3405291 "npm install error - MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component “VCBuild.exe”
").

Comment: @user3405291..thanx it worked