# How to fix MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".?

Tags: vue.js, npm-install

I am getting this error while running `npm i` in a vue project.

`MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.`

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a tricky problem, as there can be many factors. Can you tell us the solutions you have already tried ? The first should be this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658832/npm-install-error-msb3428-could-not-load-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-ex, have you tried it ?

Comment: I am trying `npm install --global windows-build-tools`. But it is taking a long time.