# I am running nodejs on windows 7 and I get below errors in the console when installing node modules (mongodb driver, mongoose etc)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Guess this has something to do something with MS visual studio, or may be not.

C:\user_management>npm install mongodb

```
> kerberos@0.0.12 install C:\user_management\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\m
ongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

C:\user_management\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\k
erberos>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\n
ode_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.

C:\user_management\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\
kerberos\build\kerberos.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\
Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Impor
t> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

mongodb@2.0.39 node_modules\mongodb<br>
├── readable-stream@1.0.31 (isarray@0.0.1, inherits@2.0.1, core-util-is@1.0.1, s
tring_decoder@0.10.31)<br>
├── es6-promise@2.1.1<br>
└── mongodb-core@1.2.6 (bson@0.4.8, kerberos@0.0.12)
```

Any suggestions on this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069699/node-packages-not-building-on-windows-8-1-missing-microsoft-cpp-default-props#), only you need set environment variable **VCTargetsPath** to correct folder for file **Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props** me is here C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120.
Good luck!

Comment: If you want to answer this question, then answer it, don't left the reference of other question.