# microsoft.cpp.default.props not found error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have Visual studio 2012 installed, I have been using the same for last 1 year.

Suddenly now I am facing this error, if I upgrade a a VS 2010 project or even create a new project. Since i do not have any admin privileges, i will not be able to install any update.

[image: Actual Error While creating new project]

How do I resolve this issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069699/node-packages-not-building-on-windows-8-1-missing-microsoft-cpp-default-props

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr