# Error while installing xml2json using node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

I tried to install xml2json package for node.js but it gives me error.

Error are as below :[image]

**My system configuration are as below :**

node.js version - v5.4.1

npm version - 3.3.12

Operating system - windows 10 64 bit

python - 2.7.11(set as environment variable )

**After installing microsoft windows sdk v7.1 it gives me below error.**

[image]

**After added package.json below error is given.**

[image]

Comment: XML2JSON is just a wrapper around [node-expat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-expat) in Windows, so you have to install that first ?

Comment: it gives me same error as above while try to install npm install node-expat

Comment: Seems like something to do with the .NET framework, I assume you have this, otherwise you can download it for free from Microsoft. Also, here's a pull for expat that seems related -> https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-expat/issues/57

Comment: .NET framework is there. As per my knowledge windows 10 have inbuilt .NET framework. I found .NET framework in C:/windows/microsoft.NET

Comment: why not to change the library ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly specify the Platform Toolset when building with **msbuild** ( triggered by `node-gyp rebuild`) . Try command below, prior running `npm`:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\Setenv.cmd" /Release /x64
```

See meaning of passed arguments below, from [SetEnv.cmd Usage](https://gist.github.com/davidcroda/e13c34c377f36080ba50):

> /Release - Create a Release configuration build environment
>
> /x64     - Create 64-bit x64 applications

**Additional explanations**

`npm install xml2json` require using [Windows SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_0) under the hood to build projects, while installing packages, with [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574(v=vs.100).aspx). You have faced situation that your Windows SDK configuration isn't compatible with required by `node`.

[Configuring the Windows SDK Command Prompt Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_0) section:

> If you do not have Visual Studio 2010, you can use the Windows SDK Command Prompt window and the SetEnv utility to configure your application build settings.

So my suggestion is to use **SetEnv** utility to fix your problem ...

**Other ways to fix problem**

MSBuild uses **VCTargetsPath** property, which cannot be located because the registry lacks this key.

Check whether key exists and points to proper path

1. Launch regedit Navigator to
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\**WinSDKVersion**
2. Inspect VCTargetsPath key. The value should be "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath64)\Microsoft.Cpp\**WinSDKVersion**\"

if key doesn't exists or has wrong value, fix problem with steps below:

1. Launch regedit Navigator to
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\**WinSDKVersion**
2. Add string key **VCTargetsPath** key
3. Set Value to "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath64)\Microsoft.Cpp\**WinSDKVersion**\"

**WinSDKVersion == v4.0** (Looks like that's value of Your WinSDK Version), so replace **WinSDKVersion** to **v4.0**.

Comment: Sure, @KevalTrivedi Does my suggestion works for you ?

Comment: I don't know. Because i am not getting your answer. Actually I am new in node.js so give me a brief idea about your answer.

Comment: I installed microsoft windows sdk v7.1 in my computer when i tried to run Setenv.cmd file it will automatically closed.

Comment: ok, have you tried to execute `npm install xml2json ` after ?

Comment: Know you should  have installed `xml2json` package, check it with `npm ls`

Comment: Please see my updated question it gives me error after added package.json file.

Comment: After added VCTargetsPath key at above location. it gives me same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102340/discussion-between-andriy-ivaneyko-and-keval-trivedi).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set the VCTargetsPath environment variable.

Have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069699/node-packages-not-building-on-windows-8-1-missing-microsoft-cpp-default-props), there are a couple of different approaches.

Setting it from the command-line by doing something like this is probably the easiest approach:

```
set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120"
```

The exact path will depend on the version of Visual Studio that you have installed.

Comment: it gives the same error as above after set VCTargetsPah through cmd.

Comment: Could you show me the command that you used to set VCTargetsPath, and the contents of the directory?

Comment: directly execute above set VCTargetsPath in cmd. and I execute above command in D:/ drive.

Comment: Does the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120" exist? If so, what does it contain? It may be that you need to use a different directory name, depending on the version of the microsoft tools you have installed.

Comment: No, MSBuild folder is missing. It is not available in C:\Program Files (x86)\ & C:\Program Files\

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code a bit
Instead of installing xml2json, install xml-js
`npm install --save xml-js`

and then use this code to convert your xml file to json

```
let convert = require('xml-js');
let xml = require('fs').readFileSync('./testscenario.xml', 'utf8');

let result = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: true, spaces: 4});
console.log(result);
```

It will work

Comment: This is a great option that works very nicely with the caveats that (1) the JSON output is text If you're using the object: true option of xml2json then just stick the output in a JSON.parse() and (2) the output structure isn't exactly the same so if you're doing subsequent parsing you'll find the XML attributes not on the objects themselves but in a ['_attributes'] array.