# npm install xml2json error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-expat

getting error while running npm install xml2json in windows cmd

resolved python & .net dependency but stuck in "fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space"

cannot install in any node js project throughout my windows system

```
npm install simple-xml2json & parallel-xml2json are working fine

>npm install xml2json --save request
npm WARN package.json @ No description
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @ No README data
npm WARN package.json @ No license field.
-
> node-expat@2.3.13 install xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild


xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodej
s\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  xmlparse.c
  xmltok.c
  xmlrole.c
  win_delay_load_hook.c
..\..\..\deps\libexpat\lib\xmlparse.c(1844): warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from '__int64' to 'XML_Index', possible loss of data [xxxxxxxxxxxx\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\expat.vcxproj]
  expat.vcxproj -> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat\build\Release\\libexpat.lib
  node-expat.cc
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat\node_modules\nan\nan.h(72): fatal error C1060: compiler is out
of heap space [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat\build\node_expat.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebui
ld"
gyp ERR! cwd xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "xml2json" "--save" "req
uest"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project               >with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Comment: node-expat is a dependency of xml2json and it has troubles installing on windows. See https://github.com/astro/node-expat#windows

Answer (score 2):

Some libraries which are based on C/C++ based libraries require to install additional libraries on an OS. Sometimes even `yarn` need extra permissions to add such libraries.

Follow [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) guide to install extra dependencies. Or use some other XML to JS/JSON parser library, like [fast-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser) which is purely based JS regx.

Comment: xml-js is another option - see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915896/error-while-installing-xml2json-using-node-js. I'd recommend following this advice and getting rid of the gyp nonsense completely.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this. If you notice this part of the command `else (node "" rebuild )` what I think is happening is that it is incorrectly evaluating `if not defined npm_config_node_gyp` as `false` and trying to run nothing instead of node-gyp. What you need to do is define your `npm_config_node_gyp` variable. You can do this like so:
`export npm_config_node_gyp=<PATH_TO_NODE_GYP_PACKAGE_FOLDER>` remember that Windows will need double backslashes. For me, it looked like this:
`export npm_config_node_gyp=C:\\Users\\781990\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v6.11.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp`

Edit:
There is another step after my fix. When executing my code, the expat bindings were missing. To fix it, add the bin folder and node-gyp executable to the `npm_config_node_gyp` variable and run `node-gyp rebuild` in the `node_modules\node-expat` folder. e.g.
`export npm_config_node_gyp=C:\\Users\\781990\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v6.11.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js`
`cd node_modules\node-expat`
`node-gyp rebuild`