# Error: Cannot find module 'xml2json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, libxml-js

When run my project package, i have getting above title error, after i trying to install that packages using

> npm install xml2json

but, i have getting below error only, can you pls give me suggestions or idea to get out from this issue...

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\podio>npm install xml2json

> node-expat@2.3.16 install D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp
 (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_mo
dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\..\..\..\deps\
libexpat\version.c
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat\build\b
inding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "xml2json"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.16 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\podio\npm-debug.log
```

Edit :: 1

After i have installed updated visual studio 2005 to 2012 im getting below error when i have run **npm install xml2json** and npm install xml2json --unsafe-perm,

```
C:\Users\Desktop\New folder\action>npm install xml2json

> node-expat@2.3.16 install C:\Users\Hoffensoft\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Hoffensoft\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (
node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modu
les\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\Users\Hoffensoft\node_modules\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\..\..\..\deps\li
bexpat\version.c
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  xmlparse.c
  xmltok.c
  xmlrole.c
c:\users\hoffensoft\node_modules\node-expat\deps\libexpat\lib\siphash.h(201): w
arning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from '__int64' to 'char', possible lo
ss of data (..\..\..\deps\libexpat\lib\xmlparse.c) [C:\Users\Hoffensoft\node_mo
dules\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\expat.vcxproj]
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  expat.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Hoffensoft\node_modules\node-expat\build\Release\\l
  ibexpat.lib
  node-expat.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Users\Hoffensoft\node_modules\nan\nan.h(75): fatal error C1060: compiler is
out of heap space (..\node-expat.cc) [C:\Users\Hoffensoft\node_modules\node-exp
at\build\node_expat.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_proces
s.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Hoffensoft\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Hoffensoft\pac
kage.json'
npm WARN Hoffensoft No description
npm WARN Hoffensoft No repository field.
npm WARN Hoffensoft No README data
npm WARN Hoffensoft No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "xml2json"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.16 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hoffensoft\Desktop\New folder\action\npm-debug.log
```

Thanks in advance, Gopal R

Comment: There are some suggestion written in the error starting from line ` To fix this, 1) install...`. Did you try those suggestions?

Comment: Do npm install xml2json --save

Comment: yes @ArpitSolanki, i try it i have installed but still not working

Comment: No @MohammadRaheem thats also getting same error only, --save is just saving name in package.json file

Comment: Are you using Angular 2/4?

Comment: No @D.V, this is a kind of middleware application..

Comment: Remove the `node modules` directory, clear the `npm-cache` using `npm cache clean --force` command and then try to install the same package by running `npm install xml2json --unsafe-perm` command and if it breaks at same dependency then use `npm install node-expat@2.3.16 --unsafe-perm` command.

Comment: No buddy@SuhasGavad still i have getting same error, no luck...

Comment: Whats the output of `npm config get registry` command?

Comment: @SuhasGavad, 
D:\xampp\htdocs\podio>npm config get registry
https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: can you try once this `npm install node-expat@2.3.16 --unsafe-perm` command. if it get installed successfully then again try to install `xml2json` package. and it would be great if you switch to latest version of `node` and `npm`.

Comment: @SuhasGavad, no, i have try which said previously, i got that same error only

Comment: check once the result of curl http://registry.npmjs.org/ command. for sure that the network is not blocking your request call.

Comment: I solved this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093298/2958314 (Extra ten characters for post limit).

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this
Use this command `npm install xml2json-light`
and change `let parser = require('xml2json');` to `let parser = require('xml2json-light');`
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. If you notice this part of the command `else (node "" rebuild )` what I think is happening is that it is incorrectly evaluating `if not defined npm_config_node_gyp` as `false` and trying to run nothing instead of node-gyp. What you need to do is define your `npm_config_node_gyp` variable. You can do this like so:
`export npm_config_node_gyp=<PATH_TO_NODE_GYP_PACKAGE_FOLDER>` remember that Windows will need double backslashes. For me, it looked like this:
`export npm_config_node_gyp=C:\\Users\\781990\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v6.11.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp`

Edit:
There is another step after my fix. When executing my code, the expat bindings were missing. To fix it, add the bin folder and node-gyp executable to the `npm_config_node_gyp` variable and run `node-gyp rebuild` in the `node_modules\node-expat` folder. e.g.
`export npm_config_node_gyp=C:\\Users\\781990\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v6.11.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js`
`cd node_modules\node-expat`
`node-gyp rebuild`