# Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props file not present in directory

Tags: c++, node.js, msbuild

while installing nodejs heapdump its giving me error

```
D:\Project\demo\AppEngage\NodeJS\Scripts\node_modules\heapdump\build\addon.vcxp
roj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\
Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm tha
t the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on
disk.
```

but Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props this file does not exist under my folder Msbuild

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069699/node-packages-not-building-on-windows-8-1-missing-microsoft-cpp-default-props)?