# Setting VCTargetsPath to multiple directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cocos2d-x, static-libraries

So, I've been trying to generate cocos2d-x static libraries, and I ran cmd as admin, and entered

```
cocos gen-libs
```

After about ten minutes, I got an issue about cpp windows props. I found out through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069699/node-packages-not-building-on-windows-8-1-missing-microsoft-cpp-default-props) that I was supposed to set the VCTargetsPath so gen-libs could use some build tools. So, I did that, ran gen-libs again, and got error
messages about the v140_xp toolset not being found. So, I then set the VCTargets path so it used that toolset. After using gen-libs again, it said it couldn't find the v120 toolset (the one it was set to use in the first VCTargetsPath change).

tl;dr I need to know how to make it so my VCTargetsPath can refer to more than one directory at once, so I can build the cocos2d-x static libraries on my machine without hassle.

If it helps any, I'm on Windows 10 64-bit, using cocos2d-x v3.15.1